# what should php code be saved as

Tags: php, html

This is my first time trying PHP out but whenever I'm saving the file as a .php file it is not opening the file. It is just showing the code. This is the code. When I save it as an html file it shows the  tag but not the php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
 echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

If you can help me that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: You need a PHP-enabled web server for this to do anything. What are you using? Is it configured correctly for `.php` files?

Comment: I don't have a PHP-enabled web server. Any suggestions?

Comment: any relation to this guy? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50092109/1415724 maybe you're in the same school.

Comment: Depends on your platform. You can use shared hosting services to dabble around, [Codepad](http://codepad.org) for trivial things, or tools like WAMP for development environments.

Comment: Funky Forty Niner - that was my first question I didn't think uploaded.

Comment: you mean to say that you and "masral" are the same person and that https://stackoverflow.com/q/50092109/ is a question by the same person?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I suspect this is some kind of YouTube tutorial that's misisng enough content people keep asking the same questions.

Comment: @tadman the OP said in [this comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092103/what-should-php-code-be-saved-as#comment87200448_50092103) *"that was my first question I didn't think uploaded"*. Which to me, means they're the same person.

Comment: @Mero so, you didn't answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092103/what-should-php-code-be-saved-as#comment87200409_50092103) from earlier. I'll ask again and I hope you'll respond and by pinging me directly as I did here. Are you and masral the same person and you have 2 accounts?