# Beginner Hello world php errors

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the hello world program to run on my school's remote server but its not showing anything and coming back with errors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

That's the code and the errors the server keeps sending back are ./hello.php: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' and ./hello.php: line 1:`'   This server runs linux and perl.  Why won't the server run this program?

Comment: try removing the dot(.) from the url ```./hello.php``` => ```/hello.php```

Comment: any relation to this guy? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50092103/1415724 maybe you're in the same school.

Comment: You need a php server in order to run php codes. That's why

Comment: My guess is that you're editing/working/running a different file. Questions's code has no  `php` syntax errors .